# Filter a Drupal view (displayed in a panel) by taxonomy term depending on domain

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-panels

This is a Views 6.x-2.x problem: On a site with many different views (many of which are blocks included in Panels that pass arguments to blocks) I would like to filter views by a taxonomy term depending on the domain the site is visited through. This filtering should be additional to a first argument (taxonomy term).

The site is configured to work with different domains, let's say example1.com and example2.com. I want to "connect" those domains to the taxonomy terms 45 and 115.

So for example:

example1.com/my_view/1
Should show all nodes that have term 1 and term 45.

example2.com/my_view/1
Should show all nodes that have term 1 and term 115.

My approach was to add a second argument (the first is the default taxonomy term ID argument). As default argument I use the following snipped in the argument handling code:

```
<?php
// Get domain.
$host = preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $hit);
$host = $hit[0];

// Select taxonomy term.
if ($host == 'example1.com'){
  $taxonomy = '45';
} elseif ($host == 'example2.com'){
  $taxonomy = '115';
}

return $taxonomy;
?>
```

This works when I use a page display with the path my_view/% (making only the first argument mandatory). But when I use it in a panel, I just get an empty view (if "no context" is chosen) or the second argument doesn't have any effect (if "term id of first/all term" is chosen).

Any ideas what could be wrong? I have really tried a lot.

Comment: Have you eneabled 'Send argument' check box?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I enabled that checkbox in the Panels pane, yes. And without the second argument, the view works fine, which shows that the argument is actually passed to the view through Panels.

Comment: So, your query is solved now?

Comment: No, not at all. I had the ckeckbox already activated when I asked my question. That is what I wanted to say with my last comment.

Comment: For the first taxonomy argument did you enable the "Action to take if argument does not validate > Show all results"?

Comment: Yes, that is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115138/why-is-views-ignoring-nid-as-second-argument/115788#115788), views ignores the second argument if the first is not present. So setting the following default argument for the first taxonomy argument solves the problem, although it's more of a workaround than a real solution:

```
if (arg(0) != 'taxonomy') {
  return 'all';
} else {
  return arg(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom module you can use **hook_views_query_alter**.  You basically pick out the "where" clause that's almost doing what you want it to and override it with your custom criteria.

```
function [custom module name]_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // pick out the right View by its name
  if($view->name == "[your View's machine name]"){

    // drupal_set_message(print_r($query->where, 1)); // Uncomment to see "where" array

    // Get domain.
    $host = preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $hit);
    $host = $hit[0];

    // Change the taxonomy term dependent on host
    if ($host == 'example1.com'){
      $query->where[0]['clauses'][2] = "(term_node_value_1.tid = 45)";
    } elseif ($host == 'example2.com'){
      $query->where[0]['clauses'][2] = "(term_node_value_1.tid = 115)";
    }
  }
}
```

You'll have to examine the $query object to determine which clause to override and the names of the variables involved - uncomment the drupal_set_message line to see it.  This technique allows you to do all sorts of tricky exceptions that wouldn't be possible with Views alone.  Clear your cache after you put this code in your module.

Comment: (Sorry, I had login problems.) Interesting approach! And it does, what it promises to do. Thanks a lot. Althoug it's not really the answer to my question, it really helps. I used it including the depth identifier. I would post it here, but the character limitation doesn't let me.